I need to do a control to verify that in each partition (BY ID) the sequence of the dates is correct
I need to do a add a column (CTRL) to verify that in each partition (ID) the sequence of the dates (REFERENCE_DATE) is correct keeping in consideration the column NUM_ROLL;
The db is ORACLE and I am using SQL DEVELOPER
The data is ordered By ID, NUM_ROLL, REFERENCE_DATE
current table with the new column that I have to create
I expect to have the new column CTRL having values 0 or 1

In SQL (not just Oracle), result sets are non-deterministically ordered (i.e. unordered) unless you have an ORDER BY clause that allows you to set the order within the result set. Your sample data does not have an obvious column that would allow you to order the results set so it is unclear how you expect to maintain the order in your results set so your question is unanswerable/impossible. You need to have a way of ordering your results first and then it may be answerable/possible.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (as text we can copy-paste and execute and NOT as an image); an explanation of the logic that you want to implement in the question (not hidden in an image behind a link); and the expected output in the question (again, as formatted text, not as an image).

If, for each PARTITION ID, you want to order the results by NUM_ROLL and then REFERENCE_DATE and check whether the previous REFERENCE_DATE is less than the current REFERENCE_DATE then you can use the LAG analytic function and a CASE expression:
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN LAG(reference_date) OVER (
              PARTITION BY partition_id
              ORDER BY num_roll, reference_date
            ) >= reference_date
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS ctrl
FROM   table_name t

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (partition_id, num_roll, reference_date) AS
  SELECT 'A', 1, DATE '2024-07-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2024-07-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2024-07-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, DATE '2024-07-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2024-06-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 2, DATE '2024-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 3, DATE '2024-06-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 4, DATE '2024-06-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 5, DATE '2024-06-10' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PARTITION_ID
NUM_ROLL
REFERENCE_DATE
CTRL




A
1
2024-07-15 00:00:00
0


A
2
2024-07-14 00:00:00
1


A
2
2024-07-16 00:00:00
0


A
2
2024-07-17 00:00:00
0


B
2
2024-06-04 00:00:00
0


B
2
2024-06-05 00:00:00
0


B
3
2024-06-06 00:00:00
0


B
4
2024-06-07 00:00:00
0


B
5
2024-06-10 00:00:00
0



Note: If you do not want to order the results by NUM_ROLL, REFERENCE_DATE and want to use a different ordering then you will need to provide a set of columns that will generate your desired ordering because without something to order the rows by then the result set will be non-deterministically ordered (i.e. randomly in the order that the rows are retrieved).
fiddle

perefect it worked!!!!! thanks a looooooot! I just modified the condition:  CASE
WHEN e1.REFERENCE_DATE < LAG(e1.REFERENCE_DATE) OVER (
PARTITION BY e1.ID
ORDER BY e1.ID_ROLL, e1.REFERENCE_DATE
)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
